# Drag estimation of Xfoil and Vortex Lattice Method?

Tags: drag, fixed-wing

I have been working on building a software to estimate lift and drag properties of a fixed wing being tested at a wind tunnel. The setup is a low AR wing with NACA0012 profile and 0.3m chord, with 0.4 span lengths being tested at speeds up to 20m/s. For modeling, I'm using Vortex Lattice Method (VLM) for estimating $C_L$ and $C_{Di}$ of the wing. In addition to this, I am planning to use Xfoil's predictions for estimating $C_{Dp}$. I am aware this is a crude estimation, but my starting point, nevertheless. With this configuration in mind, I've been running a few tests to validate the modeling behavior; but there have been some observations that I cannot wrap my head around:

1. For drag, I have the following plot as my baseline expected behavior. However, XFoil estimates show an opposite behavior for parasitic drag ($C_{Dp}$). When I change the Re from 250,000 to 500,000 (doubling the speed) (at 12$^{\circ}$AoA), $C_{Dp}$ goes down from 0.038 to 0.026. I am aware the drag force is still greater when $C_{Dp}$ is multiplied by dynamic pressure, but decrease in $C_{Dp}$ seems counterintuitive to me. [image: XFoil Estimated drag behavior]
2. Continuing off from the figure above, I expected induced drag ($C_{Di}$) to significantly decrease as speed increased. However, both of the VLM packages I experimented with ([PyVLM](https://github.com/Xero64/pyvlm) and [AeroSandbox](https://github.com/peterdsharpe/AeroSandbox)) give me constant ($C_{Di}$) at varying speeds. Is this a huge inaccuracy of VLM or am I interpreting something wrong?